# Java Calendar bug when set date is 30/12 or 31/12

Tags: java, date

I use class `Calendar` to create `Date`. But in my test case when i set date is 31/12 or 30/12, year of my date is my set year of date + 1. Example 2018-12-29 -> 2018-12-29 but 2018-12-30 -> 2019-12-30. I don't know why ? My code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        calendarBug(2018, 11, 29);
        calendarBug(2018, 11, 30);
    }

    public static void calendarBug(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd").format(date));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2018-12-29
2019-12-30
```

Comment: What happens when you use: `calendar.set(year, month, day);` ?

Comment: If not using java8 or greater use https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/

Comment: And/or set your output format to "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

Comment: @Chris623 no one change.

Comment: @ScaryWombat i try it but this code with `calendarBug(2018, 11, 31)` output is 2019-12-31

Comment: For reference, I was able to reproduce this using `calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-12"));`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Wrong data type. For a date-only value, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), not `Calendar`. Despite the names, both `Date` & `Calendar` represent moments rather than dates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`YYYY` represents for *week year*. Use `yyyy` instead.

From javadocs:

> A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between
>   the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value.
>   Therefore, the first and last days of a week year may have different
>   calendar year values.
>
> For example, January 1, 1998 is a Thursday. If getFirstDayOfWeek() is
>   MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4 (ISO 8601 standard
>   compatible setting), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997,
>   and ends on January 4, 1998. The week year is 1998 for the last three
>   days of calendar year 1997. If, however, getFirstDayOfWeek() is
>   SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on
>   January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998 then are part of week
>   53 of 1997 and their week year is 1997.

Comment: This issue keeps showing up all time here at SO and yet it is so hard to spot, nice job spotting it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks bro, glad to found it.